# Use Python to replace forward slashes in string to backslashes

Tags: python, backslash

Using Python 3.7, I have a string s defined as
`s = '//10.0.0.3/research'`.
I need some operator on s to produce `'\\\10.0.0.3\research'` as the output.

I understand about backslashes being escape characters, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what the proper `s.replace()` statement would look like to produce what I want (I need the backslashes because that's what the DOS 'net use' command needs to see when assigning UNC paths to drive letters). Ideas?

Comment: use a backslash to escape the backslash. `s.replace("/", "\\")`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: If I issue the statement s=s.replace("/","\\") on string s='//10.0.0.3/research', the reult is ''\\\\10.0.0.3\\research' (4 backslashes in front of '10.0.0.3' and two in front of 'research'.

Comment: Try doing `print(s)`. Python is showing the backslashes escaped so that you could copy paste the `repr`esentation and have it still work.

Comment: Also use backticks `\`` when you're writing code on stackoverflow, it makes it easier to read and copy paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two backslashes mean a literal backslash:

```py
s.replace("/", "\\")
```

Comment: The output for this is `\\\\10.0.0.3\\research'!!

Comment: @Mohammed wrong. Run `print("//10.0.0.3/research".replace("/", "\\"))` in a python interpreter (I ran that on https://repl.it/languages/python3 and it works perfectly fine).

Comment: @MaxiMouse then why it is showing in my python3.7.3 as `\\\\10.0.0.3\\research' !!!!, s/he reported the same in the comment below the question.

Comment: @Mohammed `'\\\\10.0.0.3\\research'` is the *representation* of the string. The actual string is `\\10.0.0.3\research`. To see it, use the `print` function.

Comment: Thanks @MaxMouse. Excellent comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to assign it back to `s`:

```
s = '//10.0.0.3/research'

s = '\\' + s.replace("/", "\\")
print(s)
```

outputs:

```
\\10.0.0.3\research
```

Comment: That gives me '\\\\\\10.0.0.3\\research'.